# Typescript: Type 'undefined' cannot be used as an index type.ts(2538)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I am trying to learn typescript and i do not seem to get my head around how to fix error `Type 'undefined' cannot be used as an index type.ts(2538)`, keeping default prop values.

Code:

```
interface PVIconInterface {
  name: string;
  size?: string;
  color?: string;
  rotate?: number
};

// Styled Components
const IconContainer: any = styled.span <{ $fontSize: string, $colorPath: string, $transform: string, theme: any }>`
display: inline-block;
color: ${({ $colorPath, theme }) => getColor($colorPath, theme)};
font-size: ${({ $fontSize }) => $fontSize};
transform: ${({ $transform }) => $transform};
`;

const PVIcon: React.FC<PVIconInterface> = ({ name, size, color, rotate }) => {
 return (
   <IconContainer
     className={`icon-${name}`}
     $colorPath={IconColorMap[color]}  //--- this is where TS gives error coz possible undefined
     $fontSize={IconSizeMap[size]}
     $transform={getTransformStyles(rotate)}
   />
 );
};

PVIcon.defaultProps = {
  color: 'normal',
  size: 'small',
  rotate: 0
};

export default PVIcon;
```

Any pointers are highly appreciated! Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Typescript compiler knows nothing about defaultProps. So its complains that colour prop could be undefined (as it is declared in PVIconInterface).

### Possible solution

Move default props logic into destructuring defaults like that:

```
...
    const PVIcon: React.FC<PVIconInterface> = ({
  name,
  size = "small",
  color = "normal",
  rotate = 0,
}) => {
  return
...
```

If you wish to see an other or more complex solutions here is a reference to a good article about defaultProps and TypeScript: [medium article](https://medium.com/@martin_hotell/react-typescript-and-defaultprops-dilemma-ca7f81c661c7)

Ps. It is my first stack answer, so if I made the mistake, please correct me :)

Comment: Welcome Jan to the stackoverflow! Your solution worked for me with additional small change i.e `$colorPath={IconColorMap[color!]}` and i have defined my interface for `IconColorMap`